# Web Scraping - Python - need assistance

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my first time posting so apologies if there is any errors. I currently have a file with a list of URLs, and I am trying to create a python program which will go to the URLs and grab the text from the HTML page and save it in a .txt file. I am currently using beautifulsoup to scrape these sites and many of them are throwing errors which I am unsure how to solve. I am looking for a better way to this: I have posted by code below.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request
import datefinder
from dateutil.parser import parse
import json
import re
import random
import time
import scrapy
import requests
import urllib
import os.path
from os import path
 
#extracts page contents using beautifulSoup
def page_extract(url):
    req = Request(url,
                  headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = uReq(req, timeout=5).read()
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "lxml")
    return page_soup
 
#opens file that contains the links
file1 = open('links.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
 
#for loop that iterates through the list of urls I have
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    fileName = str(i)+".txt"
    url = str(lines[i])
    print(i)
    try:
        #if the scraping is successful i would like it to save the text contents in a text file with the text file name 
        # being the index
        soup2 = page_extract(url)
        text = soup2.text
        f = open("Politifact Files/"+fileName,"x")
        f.write(str(text))
        f.close()
        print(url)
    except:
        #otherwise save it to another folder which contains all the sites that threw an error
        f = open("Politifact Files Not Completed/"+fileName,"x")
        f.close()
        print("NOT DONE: "+url)
```

Comment: "many of them are throwing errors" - OK, but we won't be able to guess without explicit, complete error messages.

Comment: Hi Thierry, thanks for responding. So one of the errors I am getting is an HTTPError from the urllib library. It is a HTTP 429 error for "sending too many requests".

Comment: Put a time.sleep(2) in your for loop, alternatively use a proxy like scraperapi (free trial with no credit card available)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Thierry Lathuille and @Dr Pi for your response. I was able to find a solution to this problem by looking into python libraries that are able to webscrape the important text off of a webpage. I came across one called 'Trafilatura' which is able to accomplish this task. The documentation for this library is here at: https://pypi.org/project/trafilatura/.